# How to change logging driver on a running container in docker

Tags: docker

I've got a running container with the default logging driver json-file, and would like to change it to syslog (new default). The docker engine's configuration has been updated to use syslog by default, so creating new containers w/o specifying the logging driver uses syslog. Is it possible to change the logging driver on existing containers without having to recreate them?

[docker update command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/) doesn't support it, editing container's config.v2.json and restarting the container seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#examples-10) and [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/change-logging-driver-for-a-running-container/22999/4) documentation it seems impossible to change the log driver of a docker container. One could change it to rerun the container.